# openssl hash producing partially different output - c++ ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openssl, key

Below is my code for creating a hash in openssl.
I was wondering why is my output always partially diffrent.

```
int main()
{
    char alg[] = "MD5";
    char buf[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH] = "5";
    unsigned char *testKey;
    unsigned int olen;  

    testKey = simple_digest(alg, buf, EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH,&olen);

    std::cout << "Printing key : >>";
    print_hex(testKey,EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH);
    std::cout << "<<" << std::endl;
}

unsigned char *simple_digest(char *alg, char *buf, unsigned int len,unsigned int *olen)
{
    const EVP_MD *m;
    EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
    unsigned char *ret;
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    if (!(m = EVP_get_digestbyname(alg)))
        return NULL;
    if (!(ret = (unsigned char *)malloc(EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE)))
        return NULL;


    EVP_DigestInit(&ctx, m);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, buf, len);
    EVP_DigestFinal(&ctx, ret, olen);

//  std::cout << "computed key" << ret << std::endl;

    return ret;
} 

void print_hex(unsigned char *bs, unsigned int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%02x", bs[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output :

```
3afb8ebc9c93bf6d40285736f210b7856af8bab4d040ca090043ca09f840ca09
3afb8ebc9c93bf6d40285736f210b7856af8bab490a5f909c0a7f909b8a5f909
```

As you can see only the back few characters differ.

Thanks in advance! :D

---

**Update (correct working version) :**

```
int main()
{
    char alg[] = "MD5";
    char buf[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH] = "5";
    unsigned char *testKey;
    unsigned int olen;  

    testKey = simple_digest(alg, buf,strlen(buf),&olen);

    std::cout << "Printing key : >>";
    print_hex(testKey,olen);
    std::cout << "<<" << std::endl;

}

unsigned char *simple_digest(char *alg, char *buf, unsigned int len,unsigned int *olen)
{
    const EVP_MD *m;
    EVP_MD_CTX ctx;
    unsigned char *ret;
    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    if (!(m = EVP_get_digestbyname(alg)))
        return NULL;
    if (!(ret = (unsigned char *)malloc(EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH)))
        return NULL;

    EVP_DigestInit(&ctx, m);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, buf, len);
    EVP_DigestFinal(&ctx, ret, olen);

    return ret;
} 

void print_hex(unsigned char *bs, unsigned int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%02x", bs[i]);
}
```

output :

```
Printing key : >>e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5<<
```

Comment: Your program does not obviously produce your output. I would expect "Printing key : >>" on one line, a single hash on the next, and "<<" on the third. I presume you run the program twice, removing the non-hash output? What is the input (i.e., the value of `buf`) on each run?

Comment: @chepner hey thanks for the comments, im not sure how does the removing non-hash output occur, but yes i run the program twice. the value of the buf will always be a number for example 5

Comment: You are mixing stream output with calls to `printf`. I'm not sure if that is recommended, but it's been a long time since I've done any C++ programming :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to hash a one-character string, "5", but you are telling `EVP_Digest_Update` that your buffer length is `EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH`. You need to pass the actual length of your buffer, not the maximum length it could be.

For completeness, here is what your main function should look like:

```
int main()
{
    char alg[] = "MD5";
    char buf[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH] = "5";
    unsigned char *testKey;
    unsigned int olen;  

    # Pass the true length of but
    testKey = simple_digest(alg, buf, strlen(buf), &olen);

    std::cout << "Printing key : >>";
    # Pass the true length of testKey
    print_hex(testKey,olen);
    std::cout << "<<" << std::endl;
}
```

One other caveat: you probably don't want to use `EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH` for your buffer, as that would limit the size of the message you could hash.

Comment: i changed that line to   testKey = simple_digest(alg, buf,sizeof(buf),&olen); but it still gives me the same random output at the back. anyway thanks for your help! i spot my error, i've filled it in below! :D

Comment: sizeof(buf) returns the size of the character pointer, not the length of the string the pointer points to.

Comment: hmm then what should i use? strlen? it still does not work. :(

Comment: Use `strlen`, but you also need to pass `olen` to your `print_hex` function, not `EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH`.

Comment: Thanks that worked! but would that be in 128 bit? as i need a 128 bit key.